# how to read multiple input files from stdin in bash script in nested while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, terminal, sh, stdin

i wanted to read two files from stdin in "while do nested loop" like file 1 first line and then process all file 2 input lines and then file 1 second line and process all lines from file 2 and so on.

> example code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/files/ ;
while read line1;
do 
 echo "$line1"output;
while read line2;
do
echo $line1;
echo $line2;
echo "$line1"test"line2" | tee -a output.txt ;

done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" ;
```

> i am reading file input from stdin using
> ./script.sh file1.txt
> but i wanted to input two files
> like
>
> ```
> ./script.sh file1.txt file2.txt
> i tried 
> done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" ;
> done < "${2:-/dev/stdin}" ; 
> its not working .
>  also tried file descripters
> like 
> while read line1<&7;
> while read line2<&8;
> input like ./script.sh file1.txt 7< file2.txt 8
> and it throws bad file descriptor error .
> ```

Comment: it's not clear if you really want to read 2 files at the same time  or ???. It might help to clarify if you include a small set of sample data and the expected output from those same inputs. Good luck.

Comment: i will add some more data , but i just wanted loop to read from two files from stdin .thats why i showed echo example .

Comment: also i wanted to read 1 line from file1 and loop through all other lines of file 2. and then again second line of file 2 and all lines of file 2 to execute and so on.

Comment: Verbal descriptions can be ambiguous or hard to understand. Please copy/paste the sample data in the answer below into your question and then show the expected output from those inputs. Then we will have a concrete example that we can talk about. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to both files within the inner loop, open them on different file descriptors. Here's an example using FD #3 and #4:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line1 <&3; do    # Read from FD #3 ($1)
    while read line2 <&4; do    # Read from FD #4 ($2)
        echo "line1: $line1, line2: $line2"
    done 4<"${2:-/dev/stdin}"    # Read from $2 on FD #4
done 3<"${1:-/dev/stdin}"    # Read from $1 on FD #3
```

Here's an example run:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
one
two
$ cat file2.txt 
AAA
BBB
$ ./script.sh file1.txt file2.txt 
line1: one, line2: AAA
line1: one, line2: BBB
line1: two, line2: AAA
line1: two, line2: BBB
```

BTW, a few other recommendations: You should (almost) always put variable references in double-quotes (e.g. `echo "$line1"` instead of `echo $line1`) to avoid weird parsing. You don't need semicolons at the end of lines (I used them in the `while ... ; do` statements above, but only because I put the `do` on the same line). And you should (almost) always check for error when using `cd` in a script (so it doesn't just keep running in the wrong place, with unpredictable results).

[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common scripting mistakes; I recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c
```

.

```
$ cat file2
foo
bar
```

.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r outer; do
    echo "$outer"
    while IFS= read -r inner; do
        echo "    $inner"
    done < "$2"
done < "$1"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file1 file2
a
    foo
    bar
b
    foo
    bar
c
    foo
    bar
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create some data files.

```sh
cat <<EOF >file1.txt
AAA
EOF

cat <<EOF >file1.txt
BBB
EOF
```

Now create a batch file to read them.

```sh
cat <<-'EOF' > read-files.sh
#!/bin/bash

F1=$1
F2=$2

while IFS= read -r line 
do 
 LINE1=$line
done < $F1

while IFS= read -r line 
do
  LINE2=$line
done < $F2

echo $LINE1
echo $LINE2
EOF
```

Make the script executable.

```sh
chmod +x read-files.sh
```

Now run it.

```sh
./read-files.sh file1.txt file2.txt
AAA
BBB
```

The variable `line` inside the while loop is not available outside the loop. That's why the value is transferred to `LINE1` and `LINE2`.

Comment: i wanted to access both files input inside nested while loop, like "while read line2;
do
echo $line1;
echo $line2;"  is there any way to access both input inside .